# Fit exactly bootstrap glyphicon in DIV, keeping responsive qualities

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I don't know if it is possible, I've tried everything I could, at no avail.
The idea is of having a glyphicon (or a self-made font) to always be the same size of the containing DIV. Bootstrap 3.3.7

Here's the code:
CSS

```
#insidewrap {
background-color: #FFD;
border: 3px dashed green;
z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
height:400px;
}
.big_box {
width: 60vw;
border: 1px solid red;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.icon_size {font-size: 60vw;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container col-md-12">
<div id='insidewrap' class="container">
<div class='big_box text-center'>
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode icon_size'></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I give the size to the insidewrap DIV, it looks ok when it's full screen, then, going down, the glyphicon loses the contact with the parent div.
CSS? Javascript? Tried a little bit of everything. Help.

JSFIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/RobDelp/omn9qwz1/

Comment: When you say "the glyphicon loses contact with the parent div", by parent div you mean .container or .big_box?

Comment: Big_box and insidewrapper should go along changing according to the BS grid until filling up the whole smaller screen device (cell). The idea is of following BS "screen filling changes" in a smooth way, but always keeping the glyphicon snug with big_box that is already snug with insidewrapper. Big_box is just part of the page, while insidewrapper is the whole template. Thanks for asking. Roberto

Comment: #insidewrap currently has a fixed height of 400px, do you need to keep that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think i understood what you want by looking at the fiddle. By resizing the screen i see that the glyphicon and the red box go in and out of the boundaries of the green one. So, if you want the height of the greenbox to resize acordingly, setting a min-height on it should do the work:

```
#insidewrap {
   background-color: #FFD;
   border: 3px dashed green;
   z-index: 2;
   padding: 0;
   /*height:400px;*/
   min-height:1px; /* This is the trick */
}
```

When you set a min-height, the browser will try to adjust the height of the element to the specified value unless theres an element contained that has a greater height (like the glyphicon in your example), in this case, it will end up wrapping the content, thus getting the height of its content.

See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omn9qwz1/1/

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment about the icon not following `.big_box` i think this script might help you:

```
window.onresize = function(){
    var w = $('.big_box').width() - 4;
    $('.icon_size').css({fontSize: w+'px', marginTop: '4px' }); 
};

window.onresize(); //We force it at the beginning
```

This will make the icon fill it's parent width when the browser window is resized.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15z3ewfk/1/

Comment: Hi AaronBC, I love your trick, but height is not the problem, not yet.
What I want to accomplish is to have the inside icon "break" with the outside div, insidewrap, the moment in which it goes full screen on the cell. I know it's something connected with "media" stuff, that makes the BS grid go full screen at a certain point, and the icon (that will be a website header) should follow the containing div.

Comment: I played a little with the min-width, and now the big-box is not "constraining" the icon anymore, and it's following his parent div perfectly. But the icon does not. 
UPDATED FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/RobDelp/15z3ewfk/

Comment: Oh Yes!!!
This is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Now I will have to test it with "the real code" to see if it's pixel perfect enough, but I think it is, solved my problem.
Thanks a bunch AaronBC and have a great Sunday.